# Is it Possible to Trigger Drag Events Programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using the library [Draggabilly](https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly) to add drag and drop functionality to my application. What I'm trying to do, is trigger the `drop` event (the HTML5 native one) on an instance of the CKEditor and then perform a task. Here's what I've figured out so far:

1. The CKEditor will only listen to native HTML5 events like `dragover`
   and `drop`.
2. Dragabilly does not trigger the native `drag` and `drop` events. Instead it uses `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

My question is, is there a way to use `dispatchEvent` or some similar method to simulate the `dragstart`, `drag` and `drop` events?

If there's a better solution to this problem other than the one I've mentioned, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: you can call the parts of ckeditor api that the drop() handler calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done a function for that, based on some code in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript), also I read
in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) that the form I'm doing the object is deprecated but it works to me, I'll correct that in the future but for now this can help you

```
function fireCustomEvent(eventName, element, data) {
    'use strict';
    var event;
    data = data || {};
    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
    }

    event.eventName = eventName;
    event = $.extend(event, data);

    if (document.createEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
    }
}
```

and how to use it for events for which you are asking

```
    fireCustomEvent('dragover', someDomObject);
    fireCustomEvent('drop', someDomObject, {dataTransfer: {files: [mockedfile]}});
    fireCustomEvent('dragend', someDomObject);
```

Comment: MDN indicates that `createEvent()` has many deprecated methods and `ConstructEvent()` should be used instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Comment: On chrome the drop event fires but the dataTransfer property is always missing :(